# How to bind dynamic forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, bind

I am having some trouble with some dynamically created forms in HTML. I have been using JQuery 1.7 to display checkboxes in form with ajax. Later on, I want to use these checkboxes in a form, but I can't seem to be able to retrieve the values. I read that they are not binded or something like that, and to use the .live() or .on() function. After reading the .on and /live function's api, I really am clueless of what to do next.

```
<!-- Tabbed Menu Options -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cowList').load("../php/populateTabsCows.php");
    $('#ranchList').load("../php/populateTabsRanch.php");

      return false;
});
</script>
```

then I am reading from the form and using:

```
$(function() {  
  $("#submitForm").click(function() {  
    // validate and process form here  

       var data = $('#filterForm').serialize();
       alert(data.toString());
    $.post('../php/filter.php', data)
        .success(function(result){
            $('#cowinfo').html(result);
        })
        .error(function(){
            console.log('Error loading page');
        })
    return false;
  });
    return false;   

  });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by returning false in the document ready event?!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's .on() / .click() / .submit() / etc. functions do not work in the same way that .live() did. You must call .on() AFTER the targeted HTML element is added to the DOM.

This explains further the differences between the two functions:
http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/#.T7UfLuvgjkp